# Create a List<string> from HashTable keys?

Tags: c#, collections, hashtable

Hey, how could I do this as short as possible?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Why not use a `Dictionary<string, Foo>` instead of a `Hashtable`?

Comment: Because my Foo can be generic...still possible?

Comment: Sure; if you're declaring the dictionary in a generic class `FooHolder<T>`, you can create a `Dictionary<string, T>` within it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.Collections.Hashtable ht = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
List<string> list = ht.Keys.Cast<string>().ToList();
```