# The non-invocable Hashtable.keys member can not be used as a method

Tags: c#, hashtable

Im creating an small Windows application program in c#, and using HASHTABLES i've got this error when I want to add values in a strored procedure. 
Error: 
"The non-invocable Hashtable.keys member can not be used as a method"

the error appears after hs.keys(n)

This is the code that im writting:

```
public int EscribirBackup(string nombre, Hashtable hs)
        {
            SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand();
            cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cm.CommandText = nombre;
            for (var n = 0; n <= hs.Values.Count - 1; n++)
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue(hs.Keys(n), hs.Values);
            cm.Connection = ABRIR("NORMAL");
            int i = cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            CERRAR();
            return i;
        }
```

Now, when I run the program im getting this error:

```
 'There is no assignment of object type System.Collections.Hashtable + ValueCollection to a native type of a known managed provider.'
```

on   int i = cm.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: don't you want `hs.Keys[n]` rather than `hs.Keys(n)`?

Comment: if i change it like that, the next error appears: 
you can not apply indexing with [] to an expression of type ICollection

Comment: what are you trying to do, exactly?  `Keys` is an `ICollection` of the keys in the hashtable.  You can't just grab one of the keys this way;  you would have to convert the keys to an array.  It doesn't make sense really that you are cycling through the hashtable `Values.Count` times, trying to add a single `Key` but all the `Values` each time.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Hashtable.Keys`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.keys?view=netframework-4.7.2) is a collection property (member of `System.Collections`) which has this definition:

```
public virtual System.Collections.ICollection Keys { get; }
```

Note that [`ICollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) properties doesn't expose indexer, you should convert it to other collection which exposes indexer.

Hence, you should convert it to an array or `List` instance first using `Cast<string>()`, then use square brackets to access the specified index as in example below:

```
var keys = hs.Keys.Cast<string>().ToArray();
var values = hs.Values.Cast<string>().ToArray();

for (var n = 0; n <= hs.Values.Count - 1; n++)
{
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue(keys[n], values[n]);
}
```

Comment: Hi ! I tried the solution that u gave me, but, when i run the application, the next error appears: 'There is no assignment of object type System.Collections.Hashtable + ValueCollection to a native type of a known managed provider.' Really i dont know what is Happening :(

Comment: What error you've got? Please edit the question to provide error details.

Comment: I added to the original question

Comment: I found that you should cast it first before using `ToArray()` or `ToList()` for both keys and values (see [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297558/create-a-liststring-from-hashtable-keys)), hence edited to provide string array instead of `hs.Values` directly.